# Why i get more then 1 row in select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a table:

Table : Berichten
Columns: ID, Bericht, Bericht, Klant_ID, Product_ID, Datum

I got one row in it and want to show it to the user with klant_id same as in the column, when i run the following statement i'm getting 10 rows

```
 select 
    b.ID,
    b.Product_id ,
    b.Klant_id,
    b.onderwerp
 from BERICHTEN b, KLANTEN k 
 WHERE b.klant_id = (select ID from klanten where email = 'joris@am.nl')
```

Any idea why I'm getting 10 rows instead of 1?

Comment: Just replace this line `from BERICHTEN b, KLANTEN k` with  `from BERICHTEN b` and you get what you want.

Comment: @XING: That's actually the **best answer**. There is no need to join at all.

Comment: `= (sub-qeury)` is a bit dangerous. Do `IN (sub-query)` instead.

Comment: @J. Adam: By applying a cross join with KLANTEN you are multiplying your result with the number of records in KLANTEN. Apart from that: you shouldn't use comma-separated joins anymore. The were made redundant in standard SQL in 1992!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ofcourse if we ignore the performance. Hope you agree `joins` are always better than  `subqueries`.

Comment: @XING: No, I disagree. Joins are not always better than subqueries. They can be much worse even, in some situations.

Comment: Don't you guys trust the dbms optimizer? (sub-query vs. join)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner. I agree to you. Cheers

Comment: @jarlh: Not when email is unique in the table. In that case I'd even prefer `=` over `IN` to make clear what happens. If it isn't unique, you are right of course. (This refers to your comment about `=` being dangerous of course.)

Comment: @jarlh I trust optimizer and ofcourse from the data its evident that he is looking for an email id which looks mostly likely to be unique. Otherwise your suggest is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing `CROSS JOIN` do only `JOIN` instead :

```
select b.ID, b.Product_id, b.Klant_id, b.onderwerp
from BERICHTEN b inner join 
     KLANTEN k 
     on b.klant_id = k.id
where k.email = 'joris@am.nl';
```

However, this could be easier to understand with using `exists` :

```
select b.ID, b.Product_id, b.Klant_id, b.onderwerp
from BERICHTEN b
where exists (select 1 from KLANTEN k where k.id = b.klant_id and k.email = 'joris@am.nl');
```

Answer (score 1):

your query make cross join between two tables

```
  select 
    b.ID,
    b.Product_id ,
    b.Klant_id,
    b.onderwerp
    from BERICHTEN b, KLANTEN k -- coma separated table make cross join 
    WHERE b.klant_id = (select ID from klanten where email = 'joris@am.nl')
```

So you need join  explicitly like below

```
select b.ID, b.Product_id, b.Klant_id, b.onderwerp
 from BERICHTEN b  join 
     KLANTEN k 
     on b.klant_id = k.id
     where k.email = 'joris@am.nl' -- put your condition here
```